# std::string conversion to char32_t (unicode characters)

Tags: c++, string, unicode, unicode-string

I need to read a file using `fstream` in C++ that has `ASCII` as well as `Unicode` characters using the `getline` function.
But the function uses only `std::string` and these simple strings' characters can not be converted into `char32_t` so that I can compare them with Unicode characters. So please could any one give any fix.

Comment: When you say "Unicode character", which encoding is it in? If it's UTF-8 then there's nothing more you have to do.

Comment: Before you can make any headway you need to know what the text encoding is. Until you know that, it's pointless doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char32_t corresponds to UTF-32 encoding, which is almost never used (and often poorly supported). Are you sure that your file is encoded in UTF-32?

If you are sure, then you need to use `std::u32string` to store your string. For reading, you can use `std::basic_stringstream<char32_t>` for instance. However, please note that these types are generally poorly supported.

Unicode is generally encoded using:

- UTF-8 in text files (and web pages, etc...)
- A platform-specific 16-bit or 32-bit encoding in programs, using type wchar_t

So generally, universally encoded files are in UTF-8. They use a variable number of bytes for encoding characters, from 1(ASCII characters) to 4. This means you cannot directly test the individual chars using a std::string

For this, you need to convert the UTF-8 string to `wchar_t` string, stored in a `std::wstring`.

For this, use a converter defined like this:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > converter;
```

And convert like that:

```
std::wstring unicodeString = converter.from_bytes(utf8String);
```

You can then access the individual unicode characters. Don't forget to put a "L" before each string literals, to make it a unicode string literal. For instance:

```
if(unicodeString[i]==L'仮')
{
    info("this is some japanese character");
}
```

Comment: Remark : on linux, wchar_t is actually UTF-32, but you should not rely on it.

Comment: You shouldn't use wchar_t as it is platform-dependent and not guaranteed to be able to store Unicode characters.

Comment: totally different thing. You *need* 32bit type to store any Unicode codepoint.